# Where do I get started with VBA and macros programming in Word 2007?

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint

I just came to know that macros in Word/Excel/PowerPoint can be programmed. That is awesome because I've a Word document with 70 tables for styling.

I'm a programmer but I don't know VB, VBA or VB .NET. I'm confused with these three. I'm familiar with .NET programming using C#. Now I want to write new macros. Where should I get started? What are VB, VBA, VB.NET and which one should I learn? Please suggest some material.

If I learn for Word 2007 will that help with other Office applications life Excel & PowerPoint?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a brief explanation of the different Visual Basics:

- Visual Basic 6 (VB6, or classic VB)

  - Released around 1998, this was the last iteration of Microsoft's original "Visual Basic."  It has the beginnings of object-oriented development, but it requires the Visual Basic Runtime for applications to run.  A lot of companies have used VB6 for internal business applications.  It was superceded by VB.NET and the .NET Framework.
- Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)

  - VBA shares the same code base as VB6 and in 1996 was available to be licensed to developers to include in their own applications.  This is how VBA appears in Microsoft Office, as an embedded language that can be used to control Office's various applications.  It's important to remember that VBA, which is still used to code office applications, is over a decade old and may feel as such when one is used to working with .NET.
- Visual Basic .NET (VB.NET)

  - VB.NET was a radical departure from VB6.  Though subsequent iterations of VB.NET have been referred to in sequence (e.g. VB7, VB8, etc.) by many developers, VB.NET shares very little with VB6 and VBA other than the BASIC syntax.  Many consider it more of a new evolution in BASIC rather than an evolution in Visual Basic.  Because it's entirely different from VBA and VB6, you cannot not use VB.NET code directly in VBA.
  - Because VB.NET code compiles down to the same managed intermediate language code as C# and shares the same .NET APIs, you may feel more commonality between C# and VB.NET than VB6 and VB.NET from a programming perspective.

If you anticipate doing a lot of development in VBA, I would highly recommend the [***VBA Developer's Handbook, Second Edition***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0782129781), by Getz and Gilbert.

Learning the VBA syntax for Word will certainly help you when you go to use Excel, Access, etc.  However, each application has its own API that provides a set of objects and methods unique to its domain.  For example, I'm very familiar with programming in VBA in Excel and Access, but I have never done macro programming in Word.  Although the code syntax would be the same, I'd have to learn Word's API to be able to program against it.

The nice thing about some of the Office applications (Excel, for example) is that you can record a macro, see what code it generates, and then tweak that code to do what you want.  That's largely how I got started in programming.

Answer (score 4):

There are some good answers here - I'd like to offer one more set of suggestions:

First, if supported in your environment, you can use Visual Studio 2005/8/10 and your C# skills to program against Office with "Visual Studio Tools for Office". See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063866/beginning-vsto-development/2064899#2064899) for more details.

If you want to delve into VBA instead (which I personally love because development is so fast compared to VS), start with this article **[Ten Code Conversions for VBA, Visual Basic .NET, and C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164018(office.10).aspx)** which will show you samples from all three languages. Next, watch this webcast: **[Using Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) Every Day Is Easier Than You Think](https://msevents.microsoft.com/CUI/WebCastEventDetails.aspx?culture=en-US&EventID=1032326222)**.

Thirdly- MSDN, read through this: **[Getting Started with VBA in Word 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604039.aspx)**. 99% of it applies to Word 2007. There are many other articles linked from this one or you can always go to the main page of **[Office VBA Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ff688774.aspx)** as a single jump page.

Then it's probably time to get started to directly program. See how things work, learn Word's [Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb243297(office.12).aspx), etc. You can always browse SO under the **[word-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba)** tag to see what other people are trying to do and the answers.

Comment: +1 Good links. You seem to know your way around Visual Basic. Do you have any pointers on this one? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551634/visual-studio-macro-getting-started-copy-a-definition-from-cpp-to-h

Comment: @Michael: Thanks. Unfortunately I don' know of a way to convert on this one - I've always wanted it myself for a to-VB conversion though, it would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: One day I'll take the time and write something (and post it there) hehe. thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

You always have [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/bb243297(en-us,office.12).aspx).
If you go to Microsoft Word > Developer > Visual Basic and open up ThisDocument in the left menu, you will have the editor. If you press **F2** you will get the libraries that can be used in Microsoft Word (the Object Browser). The easiest program would be the following:

```
Sub Hello()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

When you have the sub marked, press **F5** (to run).

**In the Object Browser** you will have three different objects, properties, functions and events. When you see something that strikes your interest, go to the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/bb244515(en-us,office.12).aspx) for word vba and locate it.
*[If the link changes, you can find it in the tree under MSDN Library > Office Development > 2007 Microsoft Office System > Word 2007 > Word 2007 Developer Reference > Word Object Model Reference]*

I think the easiest thing to do is to **define a problem you need fixed and try to program it**, similar to learning any other language. Don't make the problem to easy, but not to hard that you give up.